# C - How to initialise array of structures when the array size is large?

Tags: c, arrays

Say I have a structure:

```
struct foo{
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
};
```

And say have an array:

```
foo bar[1000];
```

I understand that you can initialise arrays like this:

```
foo bar[]={
{ .field_1= 10, field_2 = 20 },
{ .field_1= 30, field_2 = 40 },
};
```

This is not practical at all when the array has 1000 elements. I need to initialise all elements to a specific integer (**at compile time**) but it looks like it is not practically possible to do this unless the array is very small. It seems like an essential thing to be able to do but I can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the  loop.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I want to do this at compile time.

Comment: At compile time there aren't a lot of options.  Put the initialization in a different file and `#include` it so at least you don't need to look at it.

Comment: You can write a program that outputs the C source to initialize the full array.  Then include that source into your program.

Comment: You can put it as global variable or static variable as they are initialised at compile time.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That seems like the best of a bad situation, thanks.

Comment: Write a script in your favorite script language (e.g., Python), that generates this array and writes it into a file. Ideally, you should write it into a header file **as a macro**. This auto-generated header file should contain nothing else besides that macro (and perhaps an `#ifdef` clause). Then, in your source file, simply include the auto-generated header file and set the array to that macro.

Comment: It's not a particularly terrible situation.  We use a program to convert many of our graphics and fonts to binary data we include at compile time.  It isn't pretty to look at the files, but it works.

Comment: Compilers are theoretically permitted to optimize your loop to occur at compile-time. gcc doesn't seem to do it though (not with -O3 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a struct using a for loop  like this -

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct foo{
        int field_1;
        int field_2;
    };

int main(){

    int i;
    struct foo bar[1000];

    for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
        bar[i].field_1 = i;
        bar[i].field_2 = 2*i;
    }

    for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
       printf("bar[%d]:: field_1: %d field_2: %d\n", i, bar[i].field_1, bar[i].field_2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your solution bar contains integers which is dependent on 'i' or some other variable. But the OP has asked to initialize with specific integers and not some relational values(like i and 2*i) and that too in compile time.

Comment: It's just an example. I know all you can take value from scanf() or other source.

Comment: Yeah but initialization should take place at compile time. And scanf or other associated methods will work in runtime !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a special "generator" program, which outputs desired C *source code* for an array with 1000+ initialized elements.

Comment: Ye is looks like that is my only option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run a script in your favorite language (e.g., Python), which writes this array into a header file:

```
fileDesc = open('MyArray.h','wt')
fileDesc.write('#define MY_ARRAY \\\n{ \\\n')
for n in range(0,1000):
    fileDesc.write('\t{.field_1 = ' + '%5d'%(10+20*n) +
                   ' , .field_2 = ' + '%5d'%(20+20*n) + '}, \\\n')
fileDesc.write('}\n')
fileDesc.close()
```

Then, in the source file, simply include the auto-generated header file and initialize the array:

```
#include "MyArray.h"
...
foo bar[] = MY_ARRAY;
```